# Tensorflow large tensor split to small tensor

Tags: python, split, tensorflow

I have a tensor like below

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([batch, input]), stddev=0.1))
```

Assume that batch = 99, input= 5, and I would like to split up into a small tensor.

If x is below:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
 [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
 [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
 [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
 .........................
 .........................
 .........................
 [44.0, 55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0]
 [55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0, 99.0]]
```

I want to split up into two tensors

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
 [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
 [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]]
```

and

```
 [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
 .........................
 .........................
 [44.0, 55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0]
 [55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0, 99.0]]
```

I don't know how to use `tf.split` to split row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expedient way would be to call `tf.slice` twice.

Comment: Thanks. I used the tf.slice to slove it